# How to identify and handle the multiple intents in a single utterance

Tags: node.js, dialog, botframework

For example, I want to know about the weight and price of two products which belong to same entity called product

weight of hp laptop and price lenovo laptop.

In the above Utterance there is 2 different questions i need to track.

1)weight of hp laptop

where the Entity is product- hp and intent is weight.

2) price of lenovo laptop

where the Entity is product - hp and intent is price.

How can i handle this in LUIS?

I found the below link

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2017/02/15/how-i-improved-my-chatbot/

can somebody guide on how to do this using node js.

Answer (score 0):

For handling your scenario, you can create a LUIS app and then train it for 2 intents `price` and `weight`. To know how to train intents, take a look at [create new intent in LUIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/LUIS/luis-quickstart-primary-and-secondary-data#create-a-new-intent). And you need to [create an entity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/LUIS/luis-quickstart-primary-and-secondary-data#create-a-simple-entity-to-extract-message) `product` and then train the LUIS app with multiple utterances.

For using LUIS in node.js, you can take a look at [recognize luis intent in node js](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-recognize-intent-luis?view=azure-bot-service-3.0) documentation.

### Update

Attaching screenshots of sample luis trainings.

You could also try using Phrase list for entities as that helps in more entity recommendations.
[image]

`Weight` intent training utterances

[image]

`Price` intent training utterances

[image]

Sample trainings showing proper intents and entities for untrained utterances as well

[image]

Comment: Did you really tried this on LUIS? I also had the problem a few months ago, and trying to detect 2 intents in 1 sentence was not really good in terms of scoring of each intents, and it was doing false positive on other samples (2 intents with a "minimum" score whereas only 1 intent in the real meaning of the sentence)

Comment: Yes @NicolasR I did and modified answer to contain screenshots as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to split your utterance base on simply keyword mapping like `and` or leverage NPL packages like https://github.com/NaturalNode/natural into several utterances. And then make several requests against LUIS to fetch intents and entities.

E.G.

```
bot.dialog('multipIntents', [
    (session, args, next) => {
        let utterances = session.message.text.toLowerCase().split('and');
        session.conversationData.intents = [];
        for (let u of utterances) {
            console.log(u);
            const luisAppUrl = 'https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/v2.0/apps/16c5d360-63e6-4750-824d-e8051140cade?subscription-key=0b3c2b6dde5447a393234fc592235d67&verbose=true&timezoneOffset=0&q=';
            builder.LuisRecognizer.recognize(u, luisAppUrl, ((err, intents, entities) => {
                if (!err) {
                    let entity;
                    switch (intents[0].intent) {
                        case 'Calendar.Add':
                            if (entities) {
                                entity = builder.EntityRecognizer.findEntity(entities, 'builtin.datetimeV2.date');
                            } 
                            session.conversationData.intents.push({
                                intent: 'Calendar.Add',
                                entities: [entity]
                            })
                            break;
                        case 'Calendar.Find':
                            if (entities) {
                                entity = builder.EntityRecognizer.findEntity(entities, 'builtin.datetimeV2.date');
                            }
                            session.conversationData.intents.push({
                                intent: 'Calendar.Find',
                                entities: [entity]
                            })
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }))
        }
    //further todo
    }
])
```

For this, we can keep our LUIS model clean and semantical.

Comment: I think there is an important risk when you "split your utterance base on simply keyword mapping like `and`": it may introduce many side effects because cutting on a word may not be always relevant. For example if the brand is `harman and kardon` instead of hp in the example, you would have 3 utterances: "weight of harman" / "kardon" / "price lenovo laptop"